# how do i find a string or values in vba

Tags: vba, excel

how do i find a string or values in a range and copy to another sheet or sheet2. i know i have to use find method but i think im not using it right. what im tring to do find a string which is "ra01" and when i find ra01 copy it and paste it, into sheet2 but everytime when i loop thru my range, it doesnt find anything, thats what i did so far and so if any1 knows how to do it please help me out and this is how my range look likes i can't post any images cause i don't have enought points but i hope you understand my question.
                 10Y_RAN_ra01_CC 
                0Y_RAN_ra01_xx
                10Y_RAN_ra01_CC
               1X_RAN_ra01_XB
               ZZ_RAX_ra01_ZZ
               1Y_MMN_ra01_NN
               Y_RAN_ra01_ZZ
                10Y_RAN_ra01_CC

```
    sub find()
    dim x as string, i as long, lastrow as long, y as long
    x = "ra01"
    y =2
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    for i = 2 to lastrow
    if sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1 ).find.value= x then
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & y) = sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1 )
    y = y + 1
    end if 
    next i


   end sub()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question (which is a bit unclear) based on just qualified guess:

1. In order to find a sub-string (e.g. "ABC") inside another string (e.g. "GHKABCRT") using VBA you can apply `Instr("GHKABCRT", "ABC")` function, which return a position of sub-string (in this case, 4).
2. In order to find a sub-string  in Excel Worksheet you can use Worksheet function `Match()` which essentially is doing the same, returning the relative position (more details at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

In your particular case you don't even need these function (neither `Find()` function): just correct the syntax errors as shown below:

```
    Sub find()

    Dim x As String, i As Long, lastrow As Long, y As Long
    x = "ra01"
    y = 2

    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = x Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & y) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Next i

   End Sub
```

Hope this will help.
Regards,

Comment: im sorry i didnt understand your point, if u don't mind can you tell me where im doing it wrong.

Comment: I've added to my post your code snippet with corrected syntax. Please mark the answer accepted. Rgds,

Comment: i did it but somehow its copying "ra01"more then i expected so if i had 3 "ra01" in my range instead of copying 3 its copying 300 n go on

Comment: If you have more questions, please post them separately. Your original code snippet had several bugs and didn't compile: these bugs are fixed in my solution, and now the code compiles/runs. For additional functionality please submit another question. Rgds,

Comment: ok np i will post a another one but all im saying everything perfect but not incrementing right anyways thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks. In your new question you can include a clean solution I've posted. Please clearly specify the additional logic you want to implement. Rgds,

Comment: ok never mind i solved it, all i hade to do change Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i) instead of y and its working perfect thanks

Comment: Good! It should be working, the code is cleaned-up, so you can add more functionality or modify the existing one. Rgds,

Comment: its working perfect but if i use instr to find the string inside a string it doesnt find anything or wont work at all If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.InStr(i, 6).Value = x Then

Comment: Please accept this answer and post a different Question if you have. I am closing this discussion thread. Thanks and regards,

Comment: np i just did let me knw if you can help me out and here is the link and once again thanks a lot , thanks i really appreciate it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518194/how-can-i-use-instr-method-in-vba

Comment: THANKS i did it im sorry about it

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at your second question sometime later. Rgds,